# Couldn't match type ‘Map k0'

Tags: haskell

Here's my code:

```
import Data.Map as M

data Tile = A | T | G | C
type TileSet = [Tile]

complement :: Tile -> Tile
complement A = T
complement T = A
complement G = C
complement C = G
complement x = A

convertTile :: TileSet -> TileSet
convertTile [] = []
convertTile ts = M.map complement ts
```

When I try to compile this i get the following error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Map k0 Tile’ with ‘[Tile]’
Expected type: TileSet
Actual type: Map k0 Tile
In the expression: M.map complement ts
In an equation for ‘convertTile’:
convertTile ts = M.map complement ts
```

My understanding is that `Map` has a `(a -> b) -> a -> b` signature. `complement` returns a Tile and ostensibly `ts` will be a `TileSet`. So where is the error coming from?

Comment: Why are you using `M.map`? It's typed for a `Map`, not a `TileSet`!

Comment: I was trying to use the basic `map` function. my mistake haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data.Map.map` has type `(a -> b) -> (Map k a) -> (Map k b)` so you need to provide a `Map k Tile` as the second argument. You are providing a `[Tile]` list so you can just use `Prelude.map`:

```
convertTile ts = map complement ts
```

or

```
convertTile = map complement
```

Comment: Interesting. Just out of curiosity, how would `convertTile` look using a point free notation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly then you are trying to convert a TileSet using `map` function. The problem is that you are trying to use `map` from Data.Map which is not what you want:

```
:t M.map
M.map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
```

So, it wants a function `(a -> b)` and a `Map k a` as an input and as a result you get `Map k b`. What you really want to use is a simple `map`:

```
:t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

which does exactly what you want. So in order to fix your problem use `map` instead of `M.map`

Comment: Ah, i see my mistake now. How could i express this in point free notation?